# Order of columns in Oracle view is ignored

Tags: oracle, view

I have a problem while creating views with a procedure, because the Oracle ignores the order of columns I specified.

I create the text of the command for creating view in a loop (in every loop one view), at the end of view I execute `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE textOfCommand;`

I tried to add `/*+ORDERED */`  before select but this did not help. (I also tried to run the queries directly, not from procedure)

The generated command itself is good, also `column_id` is good, but it is ignored in oracle developer or in geomedia. I think this will be something with optimization of the query, because there are several joins in the query.

I just cannot understand why it is so unpredictable,  The order is sometimes good, sometimes not (if I run the same command several times) it doesn't depend on view, it is absolutely random, and I cannot figure out what is the reason. 
If you have any idea, please share it. Thanks

EDIT :

I have a problem with the order of columns (not rows) that are shown in oracle developer and also geomedia. When I click the tab 'Columns' in Oracle developer, a can see all the columns of view with good COLUMN_ID, but they are not ordered by this column. I thought it was just the way, that the oracle developer displays it, but also other software has a problem with it. If I run the select command, the order is good. I wouldn't mind the order in oracle developer, but the problem is the customer's software (geomedia).

here is an examle of generated sql that is created by procedure and then run by EXECUTE IMMEDIATE command at the end of each loop in procedure. : 
(there is something about 100 such a views. Tables, columns and orders is taken from one configuration table, that specifies all this. And I use GDOSYS.GPICKLISTS to identify FK and tables that should be joined)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "SOME_VIEW" AS 
SELECT /*+ORDERED */ a.ID AS "ID", 
a8.TEXT_EN AS "COLUMN_NAME_1", 
a.COLUMN_NAME_2 AS "COLUMN_NAME_2", 
a.COLUMN_NAME_3 AS "COLUMN_NAME_3", 
to_char(a.COLUMN_NAME_4,'yyyymmdd') AS "COLUMN_NAME_4", 
to_char(a.COLUMN_NAME_5,'yyyymmdd') AS "COLUMN_NAME_5", 
to_char(a.COLUMN_NAME_6,'yyyymmdd') AS "COLUMN_NAME_6", 
to_char(a.COLUMN_NAME_7,'yyyymmdd') AS "COLUMN_NAME_7", 
a.COLUMN_NAME_8 AS "COLUMN_NAME_8", 
a.COLUMN_NAME_9 AS "COLUMN_NAME_9", 
a.COLUMN_NAME_10 AS "COLUMN_NAME_10", 
to_char(a.COLUMN_NAME_11,'yyyymmdd') AS "COLUMN_NAME_11", 
a9.TEXT_EN AS "COLUMN_NAME_12", 
a10.TEXT_EN AS "COLUMN_NAME_13", 
a.COLUMN_NAME_14 AS "COLUMN_NAME_14", 
a11.TEXT_EN AS "COLUMN_NAME_15", 
FROM SOME_TABLE a 
LEFT JOIN IENC.TABLE1 a8 on a8.id = a.COLUMN_NAME_1 
LEFT JOIN IENC.TABLE2 a9 on a9.id = a.COLUMN_NAME_12 
LEFT JOIN IENC.TABLE3 a10 on a10.id = a.COLUMN_NAME_13 
LEFT JOIN IENC.TABLE4 a11 on a11.id = a.COLUMN_NAME_15
```

Comment: Can you post your CREATE VIEW statement along with the results of your EXECUTE IMMEDIATE?

Comment: Are you talking about order of columns or order of rows being off?

Comment: And you might want to check the documentation before adding random hints. "The ORDERED hint instructs Oracle to join tables in the order in which they appear in the FROM clause." http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements006.htm#sthref668

Comment: The ORDERED hint tells the database to perform joins in the order specified by the query - it has nothing (directly) to do with the ordering of columns in the result set.  It would be helpful if you could edit your post and show an example of the generated CREATE VIEW statements.  Oh, and BTW - is the data in the tables you're working with changing a lot?

Answer (score 1):

I assume what is "unpredictable" is something like

```
SELECT column_name, data_type, column_id
FROM user_tab_cols
WHERE table_name = 'SOME_VIEW';
```

If you want to order rows by some column, you must explicitly add `ORDER BY` clause.

```
SELECT column_name, data_type, column_id
FROM user_tab_cols
WHERE table_name = 'SOME_VIEW'
ORDER BY column_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try without the double quote for the columns' name.

```
SELECT /*+ORDERED */ a.ID AS "ID",  => SELECT /*+ORDERED */ a.ID AS ID,
```